# Encode String to Base64 using Delphi in TMS Web Core

Tags: delphi, encoding, base64, decoding, tms-web-core

In FMX, I could use the `System.NetEncoding` unit for encoding and decoding Base64 Strings in Delphi, but this unit doesn't seem to be available in TMS Web Core:

> [Error] uMain_web.pas(29): can't find unit "System.NetEncoding"

What is the TMS Web Core alternative for `System.NetEncoding` or for decoding/encoding Base64?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, `System.NetEncoding` isn't available for TMS Web Core.

In TMS Web Core, you can use `window.btoa()` and `window.atob()` though. `btoa` encodes and `atob` decodes.

```
var
  EncodedString: String;
  DecodedString: String;
begin
  EncodedString := window.btoa('Shaun Roselt'); // Encode String to Base64
  DecodedString := window.atob('U2hhdW4gUm9zZWx0'); // Decode Base64 String
end;
```

Answer (score -1):

We can use `System.NetEncoding` in TMS Web Core v2.3.0.0:

```
uses 
  System.NetEncoding;

procedure TForm1.WebButton1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  Encoded, Decoded: String;
  Coder: TBase64Encoding;
begin
  Coder := TBase64Encoding.Create;
  Encoded := Base64Encoding.Encode('Shaun Roselt');
  Decoded := Base64Encoding.Decode(Encoded);
  Coder.Free;
end;
```

Comment: This isn't true. I tested it on v2.3.0.0 and on v2.3.1.0. I still get the `can't find unit "System.NetEncoding"` error. Can you add your source of where you saw that `System.NetEncoding` was added in v2.3.0.0?